# in visual studio 2017 was use a model i made but i get the error Read_POLS_Chunk(): Error reading a polygon not 1-3 vertices

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 3d-model

To be specific, the program I was doing for a class and I was trying to replace a model of a teacup with a model I made in Lightwave Modeler (going to be a pyramid, but the teacher said if it doesn't show up to make it simpler, so right now it's a triangle), and when I run the program, I encounter this error.

I replaced the model with all types of models, including cubes, balls, and cones—in the modeler, but it says the same. I'm just confused and want to know why or even what that error means.

Comment: "not 1-3 vertices" which I suppose most likely indiate that your program expects each polygon to be defined in your model file to have from 1 to 3 vertices, where 1 vertex is point, 2 a line, and 3 is a triangle, and it looks like your model does not meet the cirteria, can you send us photo or a file maybe? check export settings in `Lightwave Modeler`, and make sure. try to create that triangle again maybe?